# Adjusting the height of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, flowlayout

[image]I have a top panel with a flow layout that has a textfield and label. I need to add more text fields and labels below the first line. I realized theres no real way of forcing a new line in flowlayout so I was just going to make a new panel and put it underneath the top one. The problem is theres a gap now because the top panels height is too tall. Is there a way to resize the panel so its width adjusts to screens automatically but I want to adjust the height of the new panel, so the gap is smaller. The two textfields up top are in the top panel with a flowlayout, The 3 textfields below are in a new panel with a flowlayout, is there a way to make the 3 textfields go right under the 2 textfields up top? Also, the whole frame is in a gridlayout.

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
Static JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new flowlayout);
Static JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(new flowlayout);
Static JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel(new gridLayout(2,1));
Static JPanel categoryPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0.2));
Static JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,3));
frame.pack();
topPanel.add(searchPanel);
JPanel container2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()):
container2.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.North);
frame.getContentPane().add(container2);
frame.getContentPane().add(statusPanel);
frame.getContentPane().add(catergoryPanel);
frame.getContentPane().add(btnPanel);
```

Comment: *"Any recommendations?"* 1) [`pack()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--) 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: Im using pack, and I added a picture for better understanding. Thanks

Comment: *"Im using pack,.."* Is that frame maximized? BTW - Where is that ASCII art/drawings as detailed in my comment?

Comment: @B.minnick Maybe you want to show us visually what is the arrangement of the components you wish to have.

Answer (score 5):

The `JPanel` with the `GridLayout` is the problem - It's probably added to `BorderLayout.CENTER` of the container and therefore it stretches across the whole available space. It also has equal cell sizes. Either wrap the grid into a `BorderLayout` and add it to `BorderLayout.NORTH` or use a `GridBagLayout` for the panels.

---

[image]

Here's an example that demonstrates how the panels are laid out in your example and how the are laid out in other layouts. I think this will make it clear why your `GridLayout` behaved in that way.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Example();
            }
        });
    }

    public Example() {

        // GridLayout

        JPanel container1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        container1.add(createExamplePanel());
        container1.add(createExamplePanel());

        // GridLayout inside BorderLayut (NORTH)

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 5 /* margin */)); // You could also use other layouts here, e.g. a BoxLayout
        panel.add(createExamplePanel());
        panel.add(createExamplePanel());
        JPanel container2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        container2.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // GridBagLayout

        JPanel container3 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5 /* margin */, 0);
        constraints.weightx = 1.0;
        container3.add(createExamplePanel(), constraints);
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1.0;
        constraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        container3.add(createExamplePanel(), constraints);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 3, 5, 5));
        contentPane.add(createTitledPanel(container1, "GridLayout"));
        contentPane.add(createTitledPanel(container2, "GridLayout inside BorderLayout (NORTH)"));
        contentPane.add(createTitledPanel(container3, "GridBagLayout"));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createTitledPanel(JComponent content, String title) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(content);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createExamplePanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Panel"));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY));
        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! One question, if i have 2 more panels under the original two, should I set the layout to be south for the bottom panel?

Comment: Okay so I did what you said and now the text fields are right under the first textfields, but the bottom portion of them are being cut off. Here is what I did: topPanel.add(searchPanel);
        JPanel container2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        container2.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);      Then I added the container to the frame. Im using a gridlayout of (0,1) should that change?

Comment: @B.minnick Please edit your question and include a runnable [mcve]. I unfortunately cannot reproduce the problem you are describing.

Comment: *"I added some code"* You have been advised twice to add a [mcve]. Uncompilable code snippets are ***not*** an MCVE. Do yourself a favor & actually *read* the document at the end of the link! If you don't understand it, ask us a specific question about what you do not understand.. Note that this answer is an MCVE.